# STM32 - Dynamic Memory Allocation Implementation, how to correctly implement the _sbrk function?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, stm32, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a bare-metal programming project written in C++ on a STM32F401RE board, and I need to implement `malloc()` and `free()` functions.

I know that dynamic memory allocation on embedded systems is not a good idea, but I need it.

Up to know I understood that in order to use `malloc` and `free` functions of the C standard library I need to manually implement a function named `_sbkr()`, and in order to do so I created a library with this single function and added it to the includes of the main.cpp source code.

The problem is that it doesn't work, when I try to dynamically allocate a variable it returns a NULL pointer.

Generating with gcc the assembly code of the main, it seems that the `_sbrk` function is not implemented in the final object which will be uploaded on the board.

How can I Correctly implement this function?

Comment: To build a primitive _sbrk function that could make functional GCC libc, and newlib, you have to define the init and the end of chip available memory, this is normally done defining symbols in the linker script. An example, more can be found googling around, is here: https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/boostrapping-libc-with-newlib

Comment: What tool-chain and C library are you using?  If GCC + Newlib the example implementation at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls will suffice.

Comment: "_I know that dynamic memory allocation on embedded systems is not a good idea_"... well you need to understand why it might not be a good idea to avoid the pitfalls - not just accept received wisdom, then use it any way.  It is not always a bad idea, but it can be used badly.  Do you know what you are doing?  Perhaps you should post a question about that?  Or even one about  how to avoid it; we only have your word the you _"need it"_ - there are always alternatives - this could be an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Newlib (the usual C library used with GCC on stand-alone systems), then the target specific porting layer ("syscalls") for the C library is defined at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls.

A minimal implementation suitable for standalone (no OS) environments is given there as an example:

```
caddr_t sbrk(int incr) {
  extern char _end;     /* Defined by the linker */
  static char *heap_end;
  char *prev_heap_end;
 
  if (heap_end == 0) {
    heap_end = &_end;
  }
  prev_heap_end = heap_end;
  if (heap_end + incr > stack_ptr) {
    write (1, "Heap and stack collision\n", 25);
    abort ();
  }

  heap_end += incr;
  return (caddr_t) prev_heap_end;
}
```

Note also that if you are using an RTOS or threading library you will also need to implement `__malloc_lock()` and `__malloc_unlock()` using your RTOS/thread libraries `mutex` call.

Note also that if you use ST's [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) that uses GCC and Newlib and has the syscalls layer implemented already.

Comment: nice answer! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! 
This function helped me to implement dynamic memory allocation and up to now it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

`sbrk` is a function that makes sense on a system having an MMU running an operating system that guarantees separate memory spaces for separate process.

You don't seem to have any of that. So, asking for `sbrk`'s functionality makes absolutely no sense.

What you need to do to implement that is to first implement an operating system that makes use of the MMU that your hardware doesn't have – it has an MPU.

So, all in all, no, this won't work out. `sbrk` is not something you get without an OS and without an MMU.

If you actually want to have dynamic memory allocation on your STM32, you will have to use a library (or write one yourself) that implements a memory pool, and then you can do `malloc`/`free` (or however you want to call them) yourself.

> I'm working on a bare-metal programming project written in C++ on a STM32F401RE board, and I need to implement malloc() and free() functions.

Uh-oh; bare metal, and dynamic memory allocations?

Realistically: You have a nice microcontroller, and you'll want to run an RTOS on it. No excuses, really – it doesn't make anything slower, and uses negligibly little memory, but makes your programming much safer and easier.

Most modern RTOSes have Memory Heaps and allocators. ChibiOS definitely does, [maybe you'll want to read FreeRTOS documentation](https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html) on memory management before starting anything yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Unfortunately it is an university project and it is explicitly requested to don't use any RTOS.
I'll try to look for a memory pool library or implement it by myself.

Comment: hm, do note that there's literally nothing about this that makes a difference whether you implement it on a PC in a single process' memory, or on a microcontroller: On the PC, you would use the "normal" malloc" to get, say, 1MB of RAM, and then you can develop your memory allocator to give your program chunks of memory when it calls `gios_malloc` and return them to the pool when it does `gios_free`. I'd strongly recommend making this work on your PC first, where debugging is easy, before taking the same C code, and running it on your microcontroller (where, instead of getting that 1MB from

Comment: the OS, you'd write in your linker script that there's a 1MB section reserved for this purpose, and just let your memory allocator work on that. The rest is literally identical code.) It's not quite clear what the didactic value of letting you do that on the microcontroller is.

Comment: This answer is not accurate.  It needs clarification, but most likley theis refers to Newlib C library _not_ glibc.  The Newlib library syscalls porting layer includes an `sbrk()` stub that must be implemented to support dynamic memory allocation.  For stand-alone systems the implementation is however trivial - but it still needs to be there.  An implementation example suitable for stand-alone systems is given at https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Syscalls

Comment: @Clifford no, this doesn't refer to newlib or glibc. The target the asker has to deal with comes with no full libc implementation – it's not a POSIX system by any means. You're very right, the implementation of "gimme more memory for my memory space (but there's only one global memory space)" is quite straightforward. Note how the first sentence of my answer is "doesn't make sense": it does not make sense.

Comment: I meant most likely _the question_ refers to Newlib - since that is the usual C library for stand-alone systems using GCC.  As I said; if that is the case, this answer is just incorrect.  You have over complicated it with mention of MMU and MPU (STM32F4xx don't even have an MPU), and operating systems, RTOS and additional libraries.  The OP needs to implement `_sbrk()` to support the library's _existing_ `malloc()` implementation and you are saying categorically that he does not.

Comment: A "full C library" does not imply POSIX.  `malloc()` is not a POSIX function - it is ISO C and supported by Newlib on stand-alone/bare metal systems.

Answer (score 1):

Using [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) (e.g. integrated in [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html)), the generated code will include an implementation of `_sbrk()` as needed for dynamic memory allocation. This is found in the file `sysmem.c`.